# PAR::Packer fails to install with CPAN

Tags: perl, module, cpan, par, packer

I'm trying to install PAR::Packer from CPAN on Red Hat. 
Unfortunately I get the following error during the installation and I can't figure out what is causing it:

```
cpan[4]> install PAR::Packer         
Running install for module 'PAR::Packer'
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RS/RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.018.tar.gz ok
Use of uninitialized value in scalar assignment at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 1838.
Use of uninitialized value in scalar assignment at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 1839.
Configuring R/RS/RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.018.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Use of uninitialized value in scalar assignment at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 1859.
Use of uninitialized value in scalar assignment at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 1860.
*** You have extra Perl library paths set in your environment.
    Please note that these paths (set with PERL5LIB or PERLLIB)
    are not honored by perl when running under taint mode, which
    may lead to problems. This is a limitation (by design) of
    Perl, not of PAR::Packer; but some of the problems may
    manifest here during installation.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Prototype mismatch: sub main::prompt: none vs ($;$) at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm line 221
"bsd_glob" is not defined in %File::Glob::EXPORT_TAGS at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm line 221
ERROR from evaluation of /root/.cpan/build/PAR-Packer-1.018-CWQJBv/myldr/Makefile.PL: Can't continue after import errors at ./Makefile.PL line 14
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./Makefile.PL line 14.
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL]
  RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.018.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Failed during this command:
 RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.018.tar.gz              : writemakefile NO '/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL' returned status 65280
cpan[5]>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd start with installing a newer Perl (alongside the existing one) if I were you - 5.8.8 is ancient history and may well not be supported by these packages anymore.

Comment: @reinierpost, unfortunately I'm working on a production system, so I'm not allowed to update the Perl version.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. Adding a modern `PAR::Packer` with its (modern) dependencies to your existing Perl 5.8.8 modules might break the system. Installing a brand new Perl somewhere else won't. Do you really need to do whatever you want to do with `PAR::Packer` ?

Comment: @reinierpost: yes, I have no other option, I need to compile a source code on this system. But I do understand that your comment makes totally sense...

Comment: So you can compile source code but not install applications? Interesting. In any case, I think your problem is at the policy level, unless someone else can resolve this error for you.

Comment: @reinierpost, so in the end I managed to install Perl 5.18 and the situation got normalized. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

/root/.cpan/build/PAR-Packer-1.018-CWQJBv/myldr/Makefile.PL: Can't continue after import errors at ./Makefile.PL line 14
comment above line...it seems no one is bother about this issue. and build it again.

Comment: explain some more, so that OP can understands clearly

Answer (score 0):

Change from

`use File::Glob ':bsd_glob';`

to

`use File::Glob 'bsd_glob';` in respective files.

[Perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html#EXPORTS): this exports the function excluding flags.

The **bsd_glob** export tag is actually exported in `@{$EXPORT_TAGS{'glob'}}` list (`/usr/lib/perl/5.14/File/Glob.pm` module). On the contrary, the **:bsd_glob** tag is not defined/specified.

Doing a [quick](https://www.google.com/search?q="bsd_glob"+is+not+defined+in+%25File%3A%3AGlob%3A%3AEXPORT_TAGS) [search](https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.cpan.testers.discuss/2016/02/msg3769.html)
 `:bsd_glob` tag was add in [perl v5.16.0](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perl5160delta). Code using such a tag under-line should better `use 5.016` or downgrade to (now discouraged) `use File::Glob ':glob'`.

For [POSIX flags](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Flags-for-Globbing.html#Flags-for-Globbing), use the fully qualified names, ie. `File::Glob::GLOB_NOSORT` or `File::Glob::GLOB_ERROR`.